# Inflater inflate but height is small ( looks like wrap_content and need fill_parent)

Tags: android

I have layout and I want to inflate that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >       
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

like

```
    LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
    View view; 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_free_text, null);
    ll.addView(view);
```

where ll is

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>
</LinearLayout>
```

in other xml, but problem is when it inflate it shows but height is big (fill_parent, it looks like wrap_content, but there is no wrap_content in layout). Can anybody help me ?

Comment: might be because of these 2tags..                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

Comment: replace null with parent view ,during the inflate.

Answer (score 15):

As Yashwanth Kumar correctly mentioned in the comments, the second parameter of the inflate-method should be the root view in which the new view will be inserted:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
View view;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_free_text, ll);
```

If a root view is provided in the inflate-call, the LayoutInflator calls the `generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p)` method of this root view to get some LayoutParams (basically containing information about how big a view can/should be) which will be passed to the new view.

Note that if you provide a root view, the inflated view will be automatically added to the root view via `root.addView(View child, LayoutParams params)`.

You can also pass a third parameter to the inflate-method (`boolean attachToRoot`), if this value is `false`, the new view will not be added automatically to the root view, but the LayoutParams are still set with `setLayoutParams(params)`. You can use this if you wand to add you view manually to the root view (e.g. at a specific position/index):

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llContainer);
View view;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_free_text, ll, false); // the LayoutParams of view are set here
ll.addView(view, 2);
```